# adding 2 domains each with 2 nameservers in aix 6.1 resolv.conf

Tags: resolv.conf

How would you configure the resolv.conf if you need to connect AIX to 2 domains where each domain has 2 nameservers? For example domaina has servers 10.1.2.3, 10.1.2.4 and domainb has servers 20.1.2.3, 20.1.2.4.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the server should be primarily a member of domainA, I would do the following:

```
domain domainA
nameserver 10.1.2.3
nameserver 10.1.2.4
nameserver 20.1.2.3
nameserver 20.1.2.4
search domainA domainB
```

Note that this may not be an idea solution for you - but each server should only be a "member" of a single domain. It can have a presence on other domains, and even have an A record on other domains, but the PTR for the primary IP address of that server should only ever point to a single domain.